# Puppeteer not going to next page of multipage form

Tags: puppeteer

I have a multipage form and am using puppeteer to test. Problem I have is that when I ask to click to the next button it does click through but it doesn't go to the next page of the form. I have tried waitforNavigation but it throws a timeout issue. I have tried to address the timeout issue but to no success.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setViewport({ width: 1920, height: 1080 });
  await page.goto('https://example.com/form/');

  //await page.waitForNavigation({timeout: 10000, waitUntil: "load"}); // The promise resolves after navigation has finished
  await page.click('#next_button_1'); // Clicking the link will indirectly cause a navigation
  await page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0);
  await page.waitForNavigation();
  await page.screenshot({path: 'example.png',fullPage: true});
  // other actions...
  await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: If you launch the browser with headless false what do you see?

Comment: maybe there is a element inside `#next_button_1` that should be clicked ... did you write those forms for test or is it a live website  ?